# Does irregular eating patterns and frequent lack of hunger constitute an eating disorder?

Tags: eating-disorder

If we have a patient diagnosed with ADHD who has a BMI between 16.0 and 18.5 (underweight) who has an inconsistent eating pattern and a reoccurring lack of hunger, would they be likely to have an eating disorder?

Pt. has access to food (some of which they like). Purging not present; no negative outlooks on food or physique.

Examples of their eating behavior might be (first three days of the week):

> Breakfast, *skipped*. Lunch, *skipped*. Dinner, ~700 calories. Midnight snack, ~350 calories.
>
> Breakfast, *skipped*. Lunch, ~600 calories. Dinner, ~500 calories.
>
> Breakfast, ~300 calories. Lunch, ~400 calories. Dinner, *skipped*. Midnight snack, ~200 calories.

Average daily caloric intake less than 2000; often less than 1000.

#### Research

The closest match I found is [Avoidant or Restrictive Food Intake Disorder (ARFID)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avoidant/restrictive_food_intake_disorder). This has a common condition: "**lack of interest in consuming the food**, or tolerating it nearby". Which, sort of goes inline with the Pt. not eating food very often. But, Pt. does *not* have problems with avoiding foods based on texture, taste, smell, etc.